# MIPS dynamic singly-linked lists

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I'm trying to create a linkedlist w/ dynamic memory allocation in MIPS from user inputs.

I was wondering if there is a general structure that is normally used to create nodes (structs in C)--for example maybe making it a subprocess that will be called in a conditional statement.

The struct I want to translate is this:

```
struct p {
    char name[256];
    int phone;
    float rating;
    struct p *next;
};
```

The inputs of each part of the struct will be inputted by the user (this part I know how to do and store), but I am not sure how to assign register values on the heap to accomplish this dynamically.

Eventually I will sort these values based on ratings.

Help is appreciated--thanks!

Comment: What's the platform? Dynamic memory allocation is something you usually ask the OS to do, as opposed to rolling your own. Structs are easy - just count the total size and work with offsets.

Comment: I'm using QtSpim to execute, and cannot count the total size since the user can input a random number of structs to be evaluated. I'm just practicing heap/stack access and am stuck on this.

Comment: You will need to use syscall 9 to allocate heap memory in Spim.

Answer (score 2):

In linked list,each node consists of two items:

1.**The data**

2.**The address of the next node**

In order to allocate enough memory you have to find the number of bytes you need.In your case you need 256 bytes for the array field,4 bytes for the int field,8 bytes for the float field and 4 bytes for the address of the next node..

If you want to create your fist struct you can do this:

`addi $v0,$0,9
addi $a0,$0,272
syscall`

and now you can assigning values to the struct...

For example if you want to store the number 7 in phone field you can do this:

```
addi $t0,$0,7
sw $t0,256($v0)
```

Comment: I don't necessarily need 256... just a number I chose. Is 4 enough for a string input? These will be names (eg John Doe)

Comment: every character needs 1 byte as a result if you want the name John Doe,you need at least 8 bytes.Generally it is good to take the case for a long name,so in my opinion put 32 bytes for sure

Answer (score 1):

If register `$t9` contains the address of an instance of `struct p`, you can access the fields of the struct using offsets from `$t9`.

To load the first character of `name` do `lw $t0, 0($t9)`.

To load `phone` do `lw $t0, 256($t9).

To load `rating` do `lwc1 $f0, 260($t9)   # 256 + sizeof(int)`

To load `next` do `lw $t0, 264($t9)   # 256 + sizeof(int) + sizeof(float)`

Comment: Can this be stored in a subprocess--something like "make_node" that can be called as things are read from the user?

Comment: Yes you could use a bunch of store instructions in a subroutine to store the values input from the user into the fields of the structure.